# For Loop Counter in VBA increments by one extra

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple loop counter which I expected to msg me `1,2,3...10`. Instead I get `1,3,5,7,9`and I can't figure out where this extra increment is coming from. I'm a bit rusty after layoffs so bear with me if this seems simple.

here is my code:

```
Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To 10
    MsgBox x
    x = x + 1
Next x
```

Comment: `For` increases `x` and `x = x + 1` also

Comment: You can increase or decrease any amount ,`Dim x as Double` and `for x =1 to 10 Step 0.1`   and minus >>>  `For x=10 to 1`

Comment: `Step 1` is the default so no need to write it everytime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is typical that a `for` loop in most programming languages will automatically increment or iterate through something. In most languages, it's also common to provide a way to specify the increment amount. This is the case in VBA—see [VBA For...Next documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement). For example:

```vb
For i = 1 to 20 Step 2
 'do something
next i
```

Your code is incrementing `x`, and `For` is also incrementing `x`. There are times when you want to increment the counter within the loop if some special condition is met, but not on every loop.

If you want to manually increment, then you should use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: A `while` loop does nothing automatically; something inside the loop needs to change so that eventually the `while` condition is false or the loop is otherwise exited.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers If you want a `For` Loop, you could try `Step 0` - but, at that point, it pretty much *is* a `While` or `Do` loop, so **you should use one of those instead**.  I also don't see you complaining that `MsgBox` has defaulted to `xlOKOnly` and the Application Name for the title.  Default options are a *shortcut*

Comment: Uhm NO I want a for loop. I will always write the step increment as I like my code to be clear. @Chronocidal I realize now that this is normal behavior for language's. Your comment provides no new or constrictive information.

Answer (score 3):

The `Next x` line, when referring to an integer (x) in a `For` loop, will increment x by 1

If you would like to increment by more than one, or increment in a negative direction you could use `step` at the end of the `For` line, which provides direction to the `Next` portion. Example:

```
For x = 10 to 0 step -1
msgbox x
next x
```

will result in 11 consecutive msgbox's displaying:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you would like to control X you have different options:

**Option 1:**

Let the for-loop control everything and use "step".
In this case x will raise by y at each iteration. And you should not alter x within the loop.

```
Dim y As Integer
y = 1
For x = 1 To 10 step y
   MsgBox x
Next x
```

**Option 2:**

If X depends on something happening within the loop and you don't want the for loop to alter x you could set step to 0.

```
For x = 1 To 10 step 0
    MsgBox x
    If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
        x = x + 3
    Else
        x = x - 1
    End If
Next x
```

**Alternativ option**

Having a for loop as in option 2 not altering the x would be bad practice. It is not wrong as the code is working just fine but a while loop would be a better solution.

```
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
Do While x < 10
    MsgBox x
    If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
        x = x + 3
    Else
        x = x - 1
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Sorry. But I don't see the problem with my answer. It seems like more than enough people have given you the answer about how to fix your for loop. Therefore I desided to answer by telling you about the while loop instead. Whether it is best to use for or while loop is a matter of taste and totally up to you to decide.

Comment: I have taken note of the criticism and I hope my answer is now satisfactory.